# How to search and replace in WORD a number string (d'Aboville number) at beginning of sentence?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to find and replace a number string, more specifically a d'Adoville number string that looks like this:

1.

1.1.

1.2.

1.2.1.

1.2.2.

1.3.

it always has in my case a dot at the end, and it always is the first item on the left side of a page. 
and replace it with: \item (latex code)

Thanks, h

Answer (score 0):

Although this will find more things than you have specified (e.g. it will find number strings that do not end in ".", it may still be usable.

You need to check the Use Wildcards option in Word's find/replace.

Find

```
(^13)([0-9.]@)([!0-9.])
```

and replace it either with

```
\1whatever text you want\3
```

or

```
^pwhatever text you want\3
```

(Sorry, I know that you are not supposed to replace with ^13 in a wildcard find/replace, but not sure whether it is OK to replace by "the thing you found" or not).